# equivalent of __FUNCTION__ of C lanauage in Java

Tags: java, debugging

For debug purpose, I want to print out current executing function name in Java. If it were C, I would just do `printf("%s \n" ,__FUNCITON__)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]`
is a better way since it wont create an exception.

Comment: And people say Java is verbose?!  Crazy.

Comment: clarify RPM's comment for beginners:  `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()`

Comment: From my recent test, it seems to be `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()`  ('[2]' rather than '[1]')

Comment: It would be nice to hide that complexity in a function.  But, of course, you can't

Answer (score 2):

I'd use one of the logging frameworks (logback with slf4j is probably the best one at the moment, but log4j should suffice), then you can specify a layout that will print the method name [logback layout documentation here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)